# How to set responsive image for email to mobile devices?

Tags: html, css

I have this simple table to send as email to mobile devices:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            What to put here ???
        </style>
    </head>
  <body>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" 
           style="font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; max-width: 90vw; border: 0pt solid black; text-align: left; font-size: 12pt; direction: ltr;" id="ContentBorder">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="ContentHeader">
                <td style="padding-bottom: 10pt;" id="ContentHeaderURL">
                    <img src="HeaderImage.jpg" id="imgHeader" style="height:auto !important; width:100% !important;">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="ContentBody" style="padding: 0pt;">
                    <strong>Dear Colleagues,</strong>
                    <br>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<br>
                    { { content } }
                </td>
            </tr>                   
            <tr>
                <td id="ContentLink" align="left" style="padding: 20pt 0pt 10pt 10pt; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt; text-align: center;">
                    <p style="border-bottom: 1pt solid gray; border-top: 1pt solid gray; padding: 14pt; width: 90%;" id="ContentLinkText">
                        footer row here
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

My header image size is 1024 X 331 I need it to fit different mobile devices.

The table content (e.g. the text) is fine when I set the tables width in `pt` instead of 'px' but the image is giving me a hard time, and I don't know how to make the image to fit the screen responsively so that there will be no horisontal scrolling...

I need to deliver it A.S.A.P by tody and have no idea how to approach it.

Comment: media query support is very limit in email clients, read this for reference: https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/media-query-support/

Comment: put `width: 100%` on table too

Comment: That means that having a responsive email is pretty much out of the question, so you need to design for mobile basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responsive email is absolutely possible, I create them on a daily basis.

Make sure you have the viewport meta tag in your head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Mobiles almost all read css in style tags, so will respect the styles you create!

To replace an image in an email on mobile devices wrap the image in a span with an id, then in your css hide the image and display the mobile version as a background with explicit sizes applied to the span.

```css
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  span[class=mobile-hero] img {
    /* HIDE THE ACTUAL IMAGE */
    display: none !important;
  }
  span[class=mobile-hero] {
    /* INCLUDE YOUR 320PX MOBILE HERO */
    background-image: url(320.jpg) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 320px !important;
    /* ADJUST THE HEIGHT TO FIT THE NEW MOBILE HERO IMAGE */
    height: 480px !important;
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td class="hero">
    <a href="http://www.linkhere.com">
      <span class="mobile-hero">
         <img style="display:block;" src="images/600.jpg" border="0">
      </span>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I've just tryied your solution, but it didn't work, the image is still to big and causes a horizontal scroll

Comment: did you create a mobile version of the image? also did you adjust the height and width of the image in the css?

Comment: What do you mead by "create a mobile version of the image" ?  I've just copied your code to my html page, is there anything else I need to do ?
just to clarify, I need it only for mobile, I have no need for it on desktop browsers...

Comment: the span displays a mobile image on a phone that has a width of 320px, to display this image you need to create it then tell the css where to grab this image. Also you should adjust the 320px to fit... if you're wanting this for iphone 6 then you should change this to 375px.

Comment: Is 320px an absolute size ? will it fit all devices, 4"-5" ?

Comment: 320px in the media query is the size of screen an iphone 5 uses. You will need to adjust this to fit what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I'm sending it to all kind of devices, Android and iPhone with different size screens

Answer (score 0):

While inside the table you will never make it work. Browser will always display everything in table, setting table and/or table-cell widths will be ignored (if necessary).

The solution is to make table cells blocks, set the max-width for images and use media queries:

```
@media all and (max-width: 550px) {
    table, tr, td {
        display: block;
    }
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just tryied your solution, but it didn't work, the image is still to big and causes a horizontal scroll

Comment: If email client does not provide meta-viewport, than you have no luck. Other approach is to remove table layout and use something else, paragraphs for example. Still I see many errors in your code, in some clients you will get border around images, than font family will be different...